# Docker Error when Pulling Due to API Version

Tags: docker

I installed Docker on my Windows 10 PC and I'm attempting to pull "AndroPyTool" (link [here](https://alexmyg.github.io/AndroPyTool/)). I tried pulling it in the IDE to no luck, so I opened Powershell (with admin permissions) and continue to get the following error:

```
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=alexmyg%2Fandropytool&tag=latest, check if the server supports the requested API version
```

I'm presuming this means that I need to downgrade my docker version? But I have no idea how to do so and, more importantly, to check the server API version. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

This error might suggest that the docker daemon has died.
Just restart the docker-desktop, it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Power-shell as administrator
   `wsl --shutdown`
2. Allow docker to terminate
3. Restart docker

Answer (score 0):

just wait until in docker desktop install engine and run your command again

Answer (score -2):

pls check your desktop app resource network IP & subnet .
it should work & resolve.

Comment: need an edit, and making it a more proper answer for the community