# docker desktop on windows desktop-linux builder error

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-build

I'm really really new to docker so I'm sorry if this question sounds stupid to you, but I really need help. I've downloaded and installed Docker Desktop on Windows and want to set the desktop-linux builder as a default builder but this error occurred.

A Builder error screen:

[image: A Builder error screen]

Builder error
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopLinuxEngine/_ping, check if the server supports the requested API version

Since the error message is pointing out to the API version, I've tried restart the Docker Desktop as written as an answer in [Docker Error when Pulling Due to API Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76574999/docker-error-when-pulling-due-to-api-version) but nothing happened.

I've also checked the docker version

```
docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.10
 Git commit:        afdd53b
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 09:08:44 2023
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.20.10
  Git commit:       311b9ff
  Built:            Thu Oct 26 09:07:37 2023
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you